# How can I join a Yahoo! group if I don't have a cell number, Google, Facebook or Twitter account

Tags: yahoo-groups

I have no cell number, no Google account and no Facebook account. Why can't I create a Yahoo! account so I can join a group?

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo won't let you register a Yahoo ID without a mobile number. From their [help page on the subject](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&id=SLN14992):

> One of the ways Yahoo helps to protect accounts is by requiring a mobile number to sign up. If you don't provide a valid mobile number, you'll be unable to complete registration.

They also give three reasons why:

> - Greatly reduces the risk of an abuser accessing your account.
> - If you need to recover your password, this is the safest and most    effective method to recover it.
> - Yahoo will alert you through your mobile device when we suspect    unusual login activity on your Yahoo account.

Comment: I wonder how people in 3rd world countries who share computer access and sometimes don't have mobile phones would sign up for a yahoo account. Maybe this is only country specific?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is, you can't. Not even with a Google Voice number as your "mobile" number.

The sad thing is there ARE valid reasons to have a Yahoo Account WITHOUT a cellphone.

EXAMPLE: You have your personal account, or perhaps an account for a company... but now you have a specific product or service that you want to promote via the social networks, using a Yahoo "product", say Flickr for example.

Comment: Can you make your answer a little less "rant-y"?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a Google, Facebook, or Yahoo! account to join a group on Yahoo! Groups—all you need is an e-mail address.  To join a group, simply send an e-mail to ***groupname*-subscribe@yahoogroups.com**, where *groupname* is the name of the group.  You will get mailed back a confirmation message containing a URL; to confirm your subscription you can either open the URL in a web browser or just reply to the message.

Once you are subscribed you can post messages to the group by e-mailing ***groupname*@yahoogroups.com**; you can unsubscribe by sending an e-mail to ***groupname*-unsubscribe@yahoogroups.com**.

As you can see from the following annotated screenshot, all these addresses are posted on the home page of every group.

[image: Screenshot of a group home page on Yahoo! Groups]